# Set Margin on RecyclerView programmatically

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, layoutparams

I need to set the top margin on a RecyclerView programmatically, but I get this exception:

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutParams`

Here is my code:

```
RecyclerView.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams)recyclerView.getLayoutParams();
int marginTopDp = (int)getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.margin);
int marginTopPx = (int) (marginTopDp * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density + 0.5f);
layoutParams.setMargins(0, marginTopPx, 0, 0);
recyclerView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

If I use the `ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = recyclerView.getLayoutParams` as the stack trace suggests, I cannot call `setMargin` anymore as that method does not exist for `ViewGroup.LayoutParams`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the parent `ViewGroup` of your `RecyclerView`?

Comment: The parent holding the recyclerView is a `android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout`.

Comment: how about wrapping the recyclerview in something like a linearlayout, then setting margins to the linearlayout?

Comment: While wrapping the recyclerView works, it just seems wasteful to add an additional layout just for that purpose. I have accepted the answer below because it works and does not involve adding a layout just for wrapping purposes.

Comment: TL;DR get layoutParams from RecyclerView's parent view

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try this out. You can refer to [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams.html) for more info.

```java
ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams marginLayoutParams = new ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams(mRecyclerView.getLayoutParams());
marginLayoutParams.setMargins(0, 10, 0, 10);
mRecyclerView.setLayoutParams(marginLayoutParams);
```

Comment: android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams

Comment: mRecyclerView.requestLayout(); is required to apply changes

Answer (score 7):

for me, the parent of `recyclerview` is a `constraintLayout`,

```
        val margins = (rv.layoutParams as ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams).apply {
        leftMargin = 0
        rightMargin = 0
    }
    rv.layoutParams = margins
```

or it will get cast error, viewGroup.LayoutParams can't be cast to COnstarintLayout.LayoutParams

Answer (score 1):

You need use new object of MargingLayoutParams

```
    final FrameLayout.MarginLayoutParams marginLayoutParams = new      
                      FrameLayout.MarginLayoutParams(rvContacts.getLayoutParams());
    marginLayoutParams.leftMargin = left;
    marginLayoutParams.topMargin = top;
    marginLayoutParams.rightMargin = right;
    marginLayoutParams.bottomMargin = bottom;

    recyclerView.setLayoutParams(marginLayoutParams);
    recyclerView.requestLayout();
```

Answer (score 1):

I am also facing this type of issue, Use below code to handle margin issue of recyclerview.

```
    ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams marginLayoutParams=
    (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) recyclerView.getLayoutParams();

    // here i try to set only top margin, Get dimension from dimension file.
    int topMargin =  getResources()
    .getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.top_margin);

    marginLayoutParams.setMargins(marginLayoutParams.getMarginStart(),
    topMargin, marginLayoutParams.getMarginEnd(), marginLayoutParams.bottomMargin);

    recyclerView.setLayoutParams(marginLayoutParams);
```

Answer (score 0):

Padding usage with clipToPadding="false" did the trick in my case. [Kotlin]

So I added `android:clipToPadding="false"` to my RecyclerView in xml.
Can be done programmatically as well.

And then just used:

`recyclerView.setPadding(10, 0, 0, someSpace)`

`someSpace` is dp variable in case you need it.

`resources.getDimension(R.dimen.some_space).toInt()`
P.S don't forget to create some_space in dimension file :)